# How to inject pouchdb-browser

Tags: npm, protractor, node-modules, pouchdb

I work on an web app with pouchdb, and protractor for e2e tests.

Recently, following [pouchdb documentation](https://pouchdb.com/custom.html), we switch from npm pouchdb package to pouchdb-browser package, which is more suitable for in-browser use.

It has a side effect as we also inject pouchdb from portractor in order to force some state during e2e test:

```
export namespace pouchBackdoor {
  function _inject(): void {
    browser.executeScript('return typeof PouchDB == "undefined"').then(res => {
      if (res) {
        let lib = path.join(
          __dirname, '../node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js');
        browser.executeScript(fs.readFileSync(lib, 'utf-8'));
      }
    });
  }
```

Following the modification `node_modules/pouchdb` doesn't exist anymore and our test dont pass.

A quick workaround is to re-install the complete pouchdb distribution for the dev environment, but it's not really satisfying as everything we need should be in pouchdb-browser already.

So I tried to find the equivalent of `node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js` file in `node_modules/pouchdb-browser/` folder but it turns out that i'm not able to do it.

I tried to use `node_modules/pouchdb-browser/lib/index.js` but it returns the following error:

```
Failed: unknown error: require is not defined
```

Which make sence as `require` doesn't exist in browser environment.

So my question is, does anyone tried to do the same and find a solution, or you does anyone know better how npm works and can give me any leads ?

PS: there is the contain of my `node_modules/pouchdb-browser/` folder after a clean `npm install pouchdb-browser`:

```
pouchdb-browser/
├── lib
│   ├── index.es.js
│   └── index.js
├── LICENSE
├── node_modules
│   └── lie
│       ├── ...
├── package.json
└── README.md
```

Thanks for reading !

**Edit:**

Issue open in github/pouchdb to ask for `pouchdb.js` inclusion in pouchdb-browser package:
https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6745